# How to use set_result with transacion in endpoint (Netzke gem)

Tags: netzke

I have create an endpoint for create new Client.

At first I have create Client and use transaction (see code below).

It's work normally.

```rb
  # Before add set_result
  js_method :on_new_contact, <<-JS
    function() {
      var form = this.items.first().getForm();
      if (form.isValid()) {
        this.newContact(form.getFieldValues());
        this.closeRes = 'create_user';
        this.close();
      }
    }
  JS

  endpoint :new_contact do |params|
    data_hash = params.to_hash

    Client.transaction do
      new_client = Client.new

      data_hash.each do |field, value|
        new_client.__send__("#{field}=", value)
      end

      if new_client.save!
        flash :notice => "Client #{new_client.full_name} has been created"
      else
        flash :error => new_user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      end # if
    end # transaction

    {:netzkeFeedback => @flash}
  end # endpoint
```

---

And after I have add set result for return new Client id from endpoint.

It's save new Client 3 times to my database.

```rb
  # After add set_result

  js_method :on_new_contact, <<-JS
    function() {
      var form = this.items.first().getForm();
      if (form.isValid()) {
        this.newContact(form.getFieldValues(), function(value){
            alert(form);
            alert(value);
        }, this);
        this.closeRes = 'create_user';
        this.close();
      }
    }
  JS

  endpoint :new_contact do |params|
    data_hash = params.to_hash

    Client.transaction do
      new_client = Client.new

      data_hash.each do |field, value|
        new_client.__send__("#{field}=", value)
      end

      if new_client.save!
        flash :notice => "Client #{new_client.full_name} has been created"
      else
        flash :error => new_user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      end # if
    end # transaction

    {:netzkeFeedback => @flash, :set_result => new_client.id}
  end # endpoint
```

I already try to find what the problem.

**And I found it happen when I use set_result with transaction.**

If I remove `transaction` OR `set_result` code, it will work normally.

Then how can I make it work?